# read json file with arabic characters

Tags: jquery, json

i am trying to read a json file contains Arabic characters

but it seems it keeps ignoring Arabic characters.
same code works fine with English characters.
my code:

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'file.json',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: 'json', 
        async: false,
        success: function (data) { 
         some code
        },
        error: function (err) {
         some code
        }
    });
```

my file:

```
{
  "date": "تاريخ",
  "save": "حفظ",
  "cancel": "الغاء",
  "next": "التالي",
}
```

result:

```
{
  "date": ",
  "save": ",
  "cancel": ",
  "next": ",
}
```

please advice

Comment: Did you already tried another charset? E.g. "charset=iso-8859-6"
(Arabic Alphabet (ISO))

Comment: i just tried it, but same problem

Comment: There are some other arabic charsets, don't know if it's worth trying thoygh: http://a4esl.org/c/charset.html

Answer (score 0):

What's your result?

```
<?php

   $json = '{ "date": "تاريخ", "save": "حفظ", "cancel": "الغاء", "next": "التالي" }';
   $obj = json_decode($json);

   echo $obj->date;

?>
```

By me: `تاريخ`

Maybe delete this line `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",`